# <base> tag won't change relative path

Tags: html

I am trying to connect head.php (which contains my sql connection info and stylesheet reference) to a page under **/[regular]/games/article-name.php**. Using the base tag like so:

```
<BASE href="../[regular]">
```

Does not change the base path, therefore the SQL information and stylesheet reference are not applied to article-name.php. The **/games/** is a result of a .htaccess rule. The folder does not exist.

Comment: what is this tag?...explain more

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer to this quickly. If anyone else is having problems with this, here's the answer:

Turns out that the beginning **'/'** in the `<link rel='stylesheet' href="/stylesheet.css">` lets every existing page connect to the root of the website. Without it, it looks relative to the file it's included in. Thanks to anyone who tried answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

the **/** means that the file is inside diferent folder, but your css file is in the same root as the file...